# restarting gunicorn and nginx doesn't reflect changes after pull request

Tags: django, nginx, hosting, gunicorn

Recently I hosted a Django website on digitalocean. I then edited the content of website locally and pushed them to GitHub then pulled it to server and restarted nginx and gunicorn:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Then changes didn't reflect back to live website, Just to check if I setup gnuicorn and nginx properly, I ran `sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket` I get `Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory`

```
(venv) leptitoxadmin@ubuntu1:~/pyapps/leptx$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
[sudo] password for leptxadmin:
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-02-12 05:57:58 UTC; 2h 42min ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Feb 12 05:57:58 ubuntu1 systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
```

is this the reason, why the changes don't reflect to live website? How do I solve it? thanks

Comment: an idea maybe to change something in server and restart everything and then see if its being reflected. But make sure to revert the change by git reset. Its kind of vague to know what might be wrong. Maybe manually stopping gunicorn/nginx and start them again could work as well

Comment: How do I restart gunicorn/nginx manually?
I only know how to do it through code stated above

Comment: I've tested in my server and it works just fine. Maybe check if it really got pulled?

Comment: After lots of attempts, I checked this as well. I can see those changes reflected in server side files. I changed  `style.scss` file and after pushing and pulling i see those changes in server side files. 

isn't it due to that error I mentioned above

Comment: did you use supervisor while setting up?

Comment: I followed exactly this tutorial https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cfa565b879ff1458dba08f423cb01d71

this is first time hosting a website, let me google supervisor

Comment: I figured out I didn't use it

Comment: this is very weird. In 2nd attempt I restarted droplet and it worked. Thanks for everything for taking time to comment and help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also consider reloading daemon as well

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and now i solved!!

```
./manage.py collectstatic 
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

that code can solve problem!